# How to create a darknet/Tor web site in Linux?

Tags: debian, security, tor

I have heard a lot about creating [darknet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darknet) sites lately. I also use the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) frequently.

The `tor` service is running in my Debian server at home, and it was installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

I have an [idea how the Tor network works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326369/how-to-get-tor-relay-points-through-the-linux-command-line) and also use [torify](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326599/how-to-download-file-by-faking-the-requests-ip-address/326612#326612) once in a while, in Linux, and MacOS, for doing some tests with `ssh` and `wget` over the Tor network.

I have noticed the lines in `/etc/tor/torrc`

```
#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

However, how to go from there? How are `.onion` sites/names created?
What are the basics about setting up such a service in Linux?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Creating an `.onion` service in the Tor network is as simple as editing `/etc/tor/torrc` and adding:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/www_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

After restarting the `tor` service with

```
sudo service tor restart
```

or

```
sudo service tor reload
```

The directory will be created automagically, and inside the new directory, two files are generated, `hostname` and `private_key`.

The `hostname` file has a somewhat random name inside, which is your address in the `.onion` network.

```
$sudo cat /var/lib/tor/www_service/hostname
xyew6pdq6qv2i4sx.onion
```

The names are generated in negotiation with the actual Tor network, which also explains why sites/services in the Tor network have such strange names.

There appears to be scripts for getting (using brute force?) a slighter less random name, I got an impression the added complexity is not worth the extra effort.

So actually, what you have configured now, is that all visits to in the Tor network to `http://xyew6pdq6qv2i4sx.onion/` will be forwarded to a daemon listening to `127.0.0.1:80` (localhost:80) on your server.

Now we can setup a web daemon to answer for that IP adress:port *and* only binding for localhost e.g. it does not answers requests in the local network, and in any public IP address in the "regular" Internet.

For instance, using `nginx`, change the default server configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` to:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
    server_name xyew6pdq6qv2i4sx.onion;
    ...
}
```

Install some pages, and voilá, you have a darknet site.

The actual part of installing the service per se, is not the most difficult part however. Care must be taken for not to leak informations of the real machine in:

- the security setup of the server;
- the daemon providing the service;
- the firewalling/iptables rules.

Special care must be taken of DNS leaks too, either via `dnscrypt` or `tor`.

See the answer at [resolving DNS via Tor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327432/resolving-dns-via-tor) for more information.

Such setup can be either used to setup somewhat `anonymous` sites, or more interestingly yet, due to the properties of arriving as a reverse proxy configuration, to setup a *temporary service*/download files from a network where there are no firewall rules, or public IP addresses/NAT available to setup a proper www site in the Internet at large.

Obviously, there is so much more to talk about security concerns, however it is out of scope of this question.

For multiple services in the same host, please see the related question: [How to set up multiple Tor hidden services in the same host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328007/how-to-set-up-multiple-tor-hidden-services-in-the-same-host/328008)

For an introduction to the theme, have a look at: [Setting up a hidden service with NGinx](https://www.thecthulhu.com/setting-up-a-hidden-service-with-nginx/) and [Onionshop Guide: How To Set Up a Hidden Service?](https://www.deepdotweb.com/2015/03/27/onionshop-guide-how-to-set-up-a-hidden-service/)

If having problems opening `.onion` sites with FireFox, see: [Visiting darknet/ Tor sites with Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361608/trying-to-use-firefox-to-access-darknet-tor-sites/361609)