# Remote Access to DEBIAN/ARM

Tags: debian, arm, teamviewer

I have installed Debian 8.8 ARM on some [CHIPs](https://getchip.com/pages/chip).

I tried to install TeamViewer but it has some problems, it installs fine, but when starting it crashes.

Is there any other application that we can connect to the debian machine via a ID like teamviewer, it must be by ID not by IP because those CHIPS will be inside a network.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several technologies that provide graphical remote access.

I do advise NoMachine (NX) clients.

The protocol provides compression, and the operation is notably faster compared to other alternatives.

Besides they also have a ARM binary to install, I installed it in a raspberry pi.

They have the free and the paid solutions; and have binaries for several architectures, including Linux, Windows and MacOS.

You will find it [here](https://www.nomachine.com).

They also broadcast their presence in a local network, and if the client and server are in the same network, the entry will appear automatically.

From the security point of view this solution is also more secure then teamviewer; it does however obliges you to have a direct connection to your server, be it with VPN or SSH tunnels.

Comment: problem is I dont have direct connections, they are behind firewalls, and thats why teamviewer is cool because I can connect with just an ID, any other approach?

Comment: SSH on top of tor; Reverse ssh tunnel... none of the methods particularly liked by network administrators. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327804/how-to-create-a-darknet-tor-web-site-in-linux