# Remote desktop connection to linux from windows

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

How can i connect to my desktop version of linux from windows, i need graphic mode ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364233/remote-access-to-debian-arm

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to install [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) on the Linux server, then connect to it from Windows using the default RDP client.

From their website:

> Based on the work of FreeRDP and rdesktop, xrdp uses the remote desktop protocol to present a GUI to the user.
>
> The goal of this project is to provide a fully functional Linux terminal server, capable of accepting connections from rdesktop, freerdp, and Microsoft's own terminal server / remote desktop clients.